# calculating median

Tags: java

can anyone provide me solution of how to find the median of the final cluster members that i have got in the below program....???

```
package javaapplication;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream; // to read text file line by line

public class microclustering{
private static boolean contains(String target, String value)
{
   boolean result= true;
    for(int i=0; i<value.length();i++){
            if(target.indexOf(value.charAt(i))== -1)
    {
        result=false;
        return result;
    }
    }

  //  System.out.println(count+"intersection "+a+b);
    return result;
}

private static String[] arragedata(String [] data,int i, int j)
{
    int length=data.length;
  String newdata [] =  new String[length-1];
  if(i==j)
      return data;
  if(j<i)
  {
      int temp=j;
      j=i;
      i=temp;
  }
   int temp=0;
  for(int k=0;k<data.length;k++)
  {

      if(k!=i && k!=j)
      {

          newdata[temp]=data[k];
          temp++;
      }
      else
          if(k==i)
          {
              newdata[temp]=data[i]+","+data[j];
              temp++;
          }
  }
  return newdata;
}
private static int getIntersection(String a, String b, String []database)
{
   int count=0;
   boolean flag=true;
   String [] first = a.split(",");
   String [] second = b.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<database.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<first.length;j++)
            if (!contains(database[i],first[j]))
                flag=false;
        if(flag==true)
        for(int j=0;j<second.length;j++)
            if (!contains(database[i],second[j]))
                flag=false;

        if(flag==true)
            count++;
        else
            flag=true;

    }

    return count;
}
private static int getUnion(String a, String b, String []database)
{
   int count=0;
      boolean flag=false;
   String [] first = a.split(",");
   String [] second = b.split(",");

       for(int i=0; i<database.length;i++)
    {

           for(int j=0;j<first.length;j++)
            if (contains(database[i],first[j]))
                flag=true;

        if(flag==false)
        for(int j=0;j<second.length;j++)
            if (contains(database[i],second[j]))
                flag=true;

           if(flag==true)
        {
            count++;
            flag=false;
        }


    }

    return count;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO code application logic here
           String [] database = {"abcefo",  "acg",  "ei",  "acdeg",  "acegl",  "ej",  "abcefp",  "acd",  "acegm",  "acegn"};
           String [] data = {"ecabf", "cad", "cag", "ecag", "ca", "eca", "e"};
              String format1 = "###0.00" ;               

            DecimalFormat fm1 = new DecimalFormat( format1,new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));


           boolean flag=true;
  do{
           double threshold=0.5;      // set threshold = 0.5

           int min_i=-1,min_j=-1;
           float [][] output= new float[data.length][data.length];
           for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
               for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++)
               {
                   if(getUnion(data[i],data[j],database)!= 0){

                       int b=getIntersection(data[i],data[j],database);
                       int c=getUnion(data[i],data[j],database);
                    float a=((float)b)/((float)c);
                   output[i][j]=1-a;
                   if(i==j)
                       output[i][j]=0;

                   }



               }

           } System.out.print("  \t");
              for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++)
               {
                   System.out.print(data[j]+"\t");
               }
           System.out.print("\n");
           for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
           {
               System.out.print(data[i]+"\t");
               for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++)
               {

               System.out.print(fm1.format(output[i][j])+"\t");

              if(output[i][j]>0 && output[i][j]<=threshold)
               {
                   threshold=output[i][j];
                   min_i=i;
                   min_j=j;

               }  }
              System.out.print("\n");

              }

           if(min_i!=-1 && min_j!=-1)
           {
               System.out.println("minimum distance"+output[min_i][min_j]+"\t");
                        try{
             data=arragedata(data,min_i,min_j);

           }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               flag=false;
           }
           }
           else
               flag=false;
                             System.out.print("\n\n\n");
    }while(flag==true);
       }

}
```

this is my output:

```
        ecabf   cad     cag     ecag    ca      eca     e
ecabf   0.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    0.75    0.67    0.75
cad     1.00    0.00    0.83    0.80    0.75    0.86    0.89
cag     1.00    0.83    0.00    0.20    0.38    0.43    0.56
ecag    1.00    0.80    0.20    0.00    0.50    0.33    0.50
ca      0.75    0.75    0.38    0.50    0.00    0.25    0.40
eca     0.67    0.86    0.43    0.33    0.25    0.00    0.25
e       0.75    0.89    0.56    0.50    0.40    0.25    0.00
minimum distance0.19999999



        ecabf   cad     cag,ecag        ca      eca     e
ecabf   0.00    1.00    1.00    0.75    0.67    0.75
cad     1.00    0.00    0.83    0.75    0.86    0.89
cag,ecag        1.00    0.83    0.00    0.50    0.43    0.56
ca      0.75    0.75    0.50    0.00    0.25    0.40
eca     0.67    0.86    0.43    0.25    0.00    0.25
e       0.75    0.89    0.56    0.40    0.25    0.00
minimum distance0.25



        ecabf   cad     cag,ecag        ca      eca,e
ecabf   0.00    1.00    1.00    0.75    0.75
cad     1.00    0.00    0.83    0.75    0.89
cag,ecag        1.00    0.83    0.00    0.50    0.56
ca      0.75    0.75    0.50    0.00    0.40
eca,e   0.75    0.89    0.56    0.40    0.00
minimum distance0.39999998



        ecabf   cad     cag,ecag        ca,eca,e
ecabf   0.00    1.00    1.00    0.80
cad     1.00    0.00    0.83    0.90
cag,ecag        1.00    0.83    0.00    0.60
ca,eca,e        0.80    0.90    0.60    0.00
```

i need median of ca,eca,e and ecag,cag...

Comment: Ok wow, try asking your question and removing the details. This is way too much to read.

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Don't you know how to calculate a Median?

Comment: Or, to @Amir 's point, remove the irrelevant details and only post the parts that are causing you issues.  As is, it's not only not clear what issue you're experiencing, but it'd take a fair bit of time to actually look at the whole thing to identify where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear to everyone. If you want to calculate the median value, use this approach:-

- Sort array in ascending order
- If array length is odd, the median is the middle value from the array.
- If array length is even, the median is the average of lower middle value and upper middle value from the array.

If this is not a school homework, then you can use [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) to cut down the amount of code to write. For example:-

```
DescriptiveStatistics ds = new DescriptiveStatistics();
ds.addValue(10);
ds.addValue(10);
ds.addValue(30);

// median is basically 50th percentile
System.out.println(ds.getPercentile(50)); // displays 10
```

Answer (score -1):

To compute the median, you might use a code snippet as given for example in the answer to the question ["How to calculate the median of an array, Java?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16636924/734191).